# First defined method in TypeScript class is not properly typed (but everything after it is) using functions with typed this

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm really lost on what could possibly be going wrong here. Essentially, I'm trying to make a `MyModel` class which receives some data and initialises its own values plus defines some methods that work on said data. However, the model might only receive a certain part of the data -- therefore I define `MyModel<Included extends keyof MyData>` with `data: Pick<MyData, Included>`. I now only want methods that operate on this subset of `MyData` to be callable from some model instance, so member methods are defined through a `DependentMethod([ ...dependencies], method)` helper function which returns a function that requires the proper `this` -- ie, a `MyModel` with certain attributes in its `Included` (this also adds some runtime guards so it returns `undefined` if it's called with an improper `this` anyway).

I then define `usernameCapitalised = DependentMethod([ 'username' ], ...)` etc., which works fine... except that in the class, whatever the first defined member function through `DependentMethod` has type `any` and doesn't typecheck at all. If I add a new such function before it, that one doesn't typecheck but the previous one starts doing so. If I move the first function to no longer be first, it starts typechecking again but the one that's now first doesn't. Originally I thought the issue was with my usage of higher kinded types but as you can see in my best attempt at a minimal reproduction, that doesn't seem to be the case:

```js
type UnionOfList<List extends any[]> = List[number]

export const DependentMethod = function<Dependencies extends (keyof MyData)[], R>
  (dependencies: Dependencies, fn: (this: MyModel<UnionOfList<Dependencies>>) => R):
    (this: MyModel<UnionOfList<Dependencies>>) => R
{
  if(dependencies.every(dependency => this.data.includes(dependency))) {
    return fn.call(this)
  } else {
    return undefined
  }
}

let noop = DependentMethod(['username'], () => 0)
class MyModel<Included extends keyof MyData> {
  data: Pick<MyData, Included>
  constructor(data: Pick<MyData, Included>) {
    this.data = data
  }

  // noop               = DependentMethod([ 'username' ], function() {})   // Makes usernameCapitalised work
  // static static_noop = DependentMethod([ 'username' ], function() {})   // Makes usernameCapitalised work
  // noop_arrow         = DependentMethod([ 'username' ], () => undefined) // DOESN'T make usernameCapitalised work
  // static snoop_arrow = DependentMethod([ 'username' ], () => undefined) // DOESN'T make usernameCapitalised work

  usernameCapitalised = DependentMethod(
    [ 'username' ],
    function() {
      return this.data.username.toUpperCase()
    }
  )

  useridTimesTen = DependentMethod(
    [ 'userid' ],
    function() {
      return this.data.userid
    }
  )
}
interface MyData {
  username: string
  userid: number
}

const model = new MyModel({})
model.usernameCapitalised() // No error - unexpected
model.useridTimesTen() // Error - as expected
```

What's also curious is that static member methods also count as a new "first" method, so inserting a static `DependentMethod` call also makes `usernameCapitalised` typecheck here -- as long as it's not an arrow function (even though I override the `this` type anyway). You can try this yourself by uncommenting the commented lines in the class. `DependentMethod`s outside of the class also don't have an effect even though they both operate on the exact same types, which makes me even more inclined to think this is a bug. The static members also seem to be properly typed no matter what.

Comment: Have you looked at the errors inside `MyModel`?  It tells you that the type can't be inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your example code is that the type of `DependentMethod` depends on the type of `MyModel`, which has properties whose types are determined by the output of `DependentMethod`, which depends on the type of `MyModel`, which... oops.  The type is circular in a way that the compiler cannot infer.  And the error inside `MyModel` tells you as much:

```
  usernameCapitalised = DependentMethod( // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--  'usernameCapitalised' implicitly has type 'any' 
//because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or
//indirectly in its own initializer.
    [ 'username' ],
    function() {
      return this.data.username.toUpperCase()
    }
  )
```

This ends up cascading to most of your properties and they have `any` types as well.  The fact that instances of `MyModel` behave strangely is not surprising; you pretty much need to fix the errors inside `MyModel` before you can expect the compiler to do reasonable things with it.  So I'd view the fact that the error happens on the "first" method to be a red herring; it's interesting, but I wouldn't try to fix it by changing which method is first.  Instead, I'd fix the underlying circularity if possible.

---

Now I can't be sure if the example code is sufficiently representative of your use case, but assuming it is: I see that the `fn` parameter passed into `DependentMethod` for each property of `MyModel` only depends on the `data` property of `MyModel` and not other properties.  So perhaps `DependentMethod` should not refer to `MyModel<UnionOfList<Dependencies>>`, and instead should just refer to `{data: Pick<MyData, UnionOfList<Dependencies>>`, like this:

```
declare const DependentMethod: <D extends keyof MyData, R>(
  dependencies: D[],
  fn: (this: { data: Pick<MyData, D> }) => R
) => (this: { data: Pick<MyData, D> }) => R;
```

Note: I don't worry about the implementation of `DependentMethod` here; I've changed the generic type parameters to the more conventional (if less expressive) single uppercase character; and I've changed the generic type parameter to represent the keys and not an array of keys.  Now `MyModel` has no errors:

```
class MyModel<K extends keyof MyData> {
  data: Pick<MyData, K>

  constructor(data: Pick<MyData, K>) {
    this.data = data
  }

  usernameCapitalised = DependentMethod(
    ['username'],
    function () {
      return this.data.username.toUpperCase()
    }
  )

  useridTimesTen = DependentMethod(
    ['userid'],
    function () {
      return this.data.userid
    }
  )
}
```

and your instances of `MyModel` behave as I presume you expect:

```
const emptyModel = new MyModel({})
emptyModel.usernameCapitalised(); // error
emptyModel.useridTimesTen(); // error

const usernameModel = new MyModel({ username: "Alice" });
usernameModel.usernameCapitalised(); // okay
usernameModel.useridTimesTen(); // error

const useridModel = new MyModel({ userid: 1 });
useridModel.usernameCapitalised(); // error
useridModel.useridTimesTen(); // okay

const fullModel = new MyModel({ userid: 1, username: "Alice" });
fullModel.usernameCapitalised(); // okay
fullModel.useridTimesTen(); // okay
```

---

If it turns out that `DependentMethod()` needs access to more properties of `MyModel`, then you might need to refactor it into a base class with such properties in them, and an extending class without them, and have `DependentMethod()` refer only to the base class.  The idea is to make sure that your types are "grounded" as opposed to circular.

Okay, hope that helps give you some direction.  Good luck!

[Playground Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aicx2QbwFgAoZZAVwGdoQ4BbCALmUrClAHMSyrpgATZiHJ0ARtBIBfZCRL8ICADZwoKBAHsQrZJggAHCCHnhUEMAAt1g5AB5MyCAA9IRysgDWEdOphosOOAAaZAAlAD4ACm5keQMjQwRgCEpmTABtAF1A6JgQZgiLYBSCGIDmAAVgBHcbDGxcYMww5EkASmQAXmaQknau5ALzIuZ8UtwKqpq6gMbmts7ugG5ZYiU4SjcMVCsIRRsAaQdnQ343T29fadxmolIxuAnq2v8G5H2wlbINLTZyBDB1FAIvwyshKk8rkE3mF2rcyGRCpQAHQg3Cde7RSSfCjUKC0BgAYTgemAuEURQg-HRujixjApgsViidzIaQA5Lw8fQIGystEyDByCB-sBNANYfz4aowOQ8chESiAkjOfiIEiAQBVPQGKBE6gRVqSrF3Q3EaKcgQAFWADEolsM1P0J0M9LMln4zPhyHZFv4vOyLOQguFYFFIHFBElZGlsvDCtRcGVuIERuipuNJG+2ggdD0YHQ23kinRIAgAHc-IXdhF8G0SDm8wWdookzRuUSSWSKR7WotkAB6fsOKBQQH13P5qst33W232kAGvuD4ejqArLNgHFthhTkvlyvNmtbrkMZgAIgAguSkGeWr2SCruVPWyeIB3SXBydQe0uh+p3HA6APriqrPjONrJPOi4DkO0CruumjaL6u4dMgpYVlsh6jL6zAAIx3ssxDIc2L6qu+XbftBy5wWORHJvwYH0bOkGGFRf4AUBZqrIhm6CooigoWh+6YUWR44cguHBI+p7IJe14QLebSEXxAkkdJb7Eh+X6UmxyD-oBJAqYxfD8Mxdqsb2MF6RxQA)

Comment: Thank you! I'm using the Atom TypeScript IDE and never bothered to actually compile the code figuring I was getting all the information I could, but for some reason it withheld that "because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer." I knew what I was doing was a bit fishy but wanted it to work badly enough that when I saw it was working for _some_ members, I just went with it.

Comment: I have small concerns about the replaced DependentMethod though. In my real code, I have a `Model` baseclass and then multiple classes which extend it, some of which might have some overlap of data.. It feels like if I'm just saying "`this` needs to have data which includes username" I'm losing the information that this is actually something that works exclusively on `User`s. Not that that it would ever matter in practice, but... In my code I settled for `capitaliseUsername(this: User<'username'>)` which (maybe you would know why) works despite what seems like equivalent circular referencing.